# Big query error:Failed to parse input string

Tags: google-bigquery

Using Standard sql query but getting subject mentioned error(Failed to parse input string).

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  date, 
  EXTRACT(DAY FROM date) AS day_of_week,
  EXTRACT(WEEK FROM date) AS week_of_year,
  FORMAT_DATE("%y-%m", date) AS yyyymm
FROM( 
  SELECT PARSE_DATE('%y%m%d', date) date, campaign
  FROM `tech-team-staging-2019.DFW_GA_Data_v1_05122019.DFW_G_Analytics_Predicted_data_v1_05122019`
  GROUP BY 1,2
)
```

Comment: Please structure your code in a code block so it's more readable

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

Note: it is not clear what your `data` field look like - so below are the options

in case if your `date` field is a string with YYYY-MM-DD - you should use below

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  date, 
  EXTRACT(DAY FROM date) AS day_of_week,
  EXTRACT(WEEK FROM date) AS week_of_year,
  FORMAT_DATE("%Y-%m", date) AS yyyymm
FROM( 
  SELECT PARSE_DATE('%Y-%m-%d', date) date, campaign
  FROM `tech-team-staging-2019.DFW_GA_Data_v1_05122019.DFW_G_Analytics_Predicted_data_v1_05122019`
  GROUP BY 1,2
)
```

in case if it is - YY-MM-DD

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  date, 
  EXTRACT(DAY FROM date) AS day_of_week,
  EXTRACT(WEEK FROM date) AS week_of_year,
  FORMAT_DATE("%Y-%m", date) AS yyyymm
FROM( 
  SELECT PARSE_DATE('%y-%m-%d', date) date, campaign
  FROM `tech-team-staging-2019.DFW_GA_Data_v1_05122019.DFW_G_Analytics_Predicted_data_v1_05122019`
  GROUP BY 1,2
)
```

finally, if it is YYMMDD

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  date, 
  EXTRACT(DAY FROM date) AS day_of_week,
  EXTRACT(WEEK FROM date) AS week_of_year,
  FORMAT_DATE("%Y-%m", date) AS yyyymm
FROM( 
  SELECT PARSE_DATE('%y%m%d', date) date, campaign
  FROM `tech-team-staging-2019.DFW_GA_Data_v1_05122019.DFW_G_Analytics_Predicted_data_v1_05122019`
  GROUP BY 1,2
)
```

and yet one more - YYYYMMDD

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  date, 
  EXTRACT(DAY FROM date) AS day_of_week,
  EXTRACT(WEEK FROM date) AS week_of_year,
  FORMAT_DATE("%Y-%m", date) AS yyyymm
FROM( 
  SELECT PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', date) date, campaign
  FROM `tech-team-staging-2019.DFW_GA_Data_v1_05122019.DFW_G_Analytics_Predicted_data_v1_05122019`
  GROUP BY 1,2
)
```

Comment: thanks for your feedback all the queries are correct as mine but still facing same problem, getting same error message while running the queries. Moreover date format in schema is String Type (20191205). please share your experience with this.

Comment: have you tried .... SELECT PARSE_DATE("%Y%m%d", "20191205") as parsed;